# Checkboxes not getting checked on load in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a project using Vue.js and Laravel. I have some checkboxes to select instruments(music). 
Let me explain what i am trying to do- 
there is list of instruments with checkboxes...
On load i need to show what instruments already user has selected those checkboxes should be checked.

so here is my code

```
 <div v-for="(instrument, index) in instruments">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :id="index"
    v-model="selectedInstruments"
    :value="instrument"
  />
  <label :for="index">{{ instrument.instrument }}</label>
</div>


  data() {
    return {
      instruments: [
        { id: 1, instrument: "guitar", created_at: null, updated_at: null },
        { id: 2, instrument: "drums", created_at: null, updated_at: null },
        { id: 3, instrument: "piano", created_at: null, updated_at: null }
      ],
      selectedInstruments: [
        { id: 2, instrument: "drums", created_at: null, updated_at: null }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Here everything is working fine but when the same data is coming from axios checkboxes are not checked. 
[Here is the link for sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8x762954m8)

Thanks in Advance.

**UPDATED**

here is axios code

```
        created(){
                getAllLists(){
            axios.get('/all-lists')
                 .then(response=>{
                  this.instruments = response.data;
                 })
          }

     this.selectedInstruments = this.currentList; 
          }

// this.currentList is a prop which is passed in blade file it is getting same structured data as above array from axios
```

Comment: Can you please post your axios code where you set the selectedInstruments?

Comment: Going to be hard to tell how to fix this without seeing how you are doing the axios call, since that's the part that's not working.

Comment: @nemesv Please check updated question

Comment: That axios request isn't needed to see that htis is not working.  The selectedInstruments is an array; you are binding an array to a checkbox.  You should bind a boolean attribute to the checkbox...

Comment: You can bind multiple checkboxes to one array, @DavidHeremans. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: @DavidHeremans ... If there is single checkbox then it would be boolean but here is the group so need to bind an array. [here is the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox)

Comment: okay - new one for me - thanks for clarifying!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a brittle choice in modeling. The object in `selectedInstruments` is not actually one of the objects in `instruments`. If it looks *exactly like* one of them, Vue seems to be willing to call it a match. But if there's a mismatch in, say `created_at`, they are not the same and no box will be checked.

A better idea would be to use the `id` as the `value`:

```
 <input
    type="checkbox"
    :id="index"
    v-model="selectedInstruments"
    :value="instrument.id"
  />
```

then you just have an array of `id`s, which is less likely to mismatch strangely. You can make a `computed` to turn your array of `id`s into an array of items from `instruments` if you need to.

This ought to work as the computed:

```
selectedInstrumentObjects() {
  return this.selectedInstruments.map((id) => this.instruments.find((obj) => obj.id === id));
}
```

I've updated your sandbox to use it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q4vlpmkm5).

Comment: I was just gonna ask whether it's not because the fact that value in this example is an object which might differ accordingto vue! :-)

Comment: They are same because they getting fetched from the same table    using Laravel relationship.

Comment: Oh yes. They are bit different! just noticed! @Roy can you please give lil bit idea how i can make computed property here?